# Set path of javascript files and css files after URL rewriting rules in .htaccess

Tags: javascript, php, css, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am currently (trying) rewriting my URLs by creating rules in .htaccess file.
Quite simple for the moment my .htaccess is as folow:

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks  
 RewriteEngine on

 AddType text/css .css  
 RewriteRule ^lunettes-collection/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ lunettes-collection.php?supplier=$1&type=$2 [L]
```

So my old url is `http://localhost/myoptical/lunettes-collection.php?supplier=all&type=vue` (and works perfectly)
And my new url is : `http://localhost/myoptical/lunettes-collection/all/vue` (and has no style and js)

When I reach the new url I got the content of the page but I got the following error in the console log.

`GET http://localhost/myoptical/lunettes-collection/all/css/owl.transitions.css
GET http://localhost/myoptical/lunettes-collection/all/myoptical/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js`

As I understand there is a problem on the path of each file.
How I can specificy the right path to my script/css files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to either change all your links to absolute URL's or create a relative URL base in your page header (between the `<head>` and `</head>` tags)

```
<base href="/myoptical/" />
```

Or change all your urls so that they start with `/myoptical/`.

Comment: Hi thanks, for your help. In fact it works now when I set the /myoptical/ before the file. But I do not understand how do you insert the `<base href="/myoptical/"/>` and how do you use it (fyi, i am in php?

Comment: @Skunkies as my answer says: between the `<head>` and `</head>` tags